# Submit Button for Right Answer?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, submit

Got stuck on something that I thought would be quite straight forward.

I am trying to create a form, where you are asked a question and you need to input the right answer and submit it. So I need to make a submit button that only works if an exact value is typed in a text field of some sort. If the answer is different, then the button should just do nothing (or make a sound or something).

Any suggestions on where to start on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Usually you should be checking on the server. Otherwise the user can look at the code to see which is the right answer.

Comment: But you can set the submit button's `disabled` attribute to prevent submitting the form. When they type the correct answer, you remove the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
function check() {
  var correctAnswer = "4";
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("ELEMENT_ID").value;

  if(inputValue !== correcetAnswer) {
    return false;
  };
};
```

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return check()">

</form>
```

Just run a function with the `onsubmit` attribute and have the function return false if the answer is wrong. Use the `value` property of the input box to get user input.

Comment: You need to use `return check()` in the onsubmit.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to first of all make a function in JavaScript something like CorrectAnswer which stores the right answer and then when the user clicks on it, you would need to use on click where you’d need to use CorrectAnswer id where the script checks for the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, you can disable the button if the answer is wrong.
Now, you haven’t given any code. So, I am showing an example only:

We gonna use javascript for this. Let's create a form

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="text" id="question1" onchange="check()">
<input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

We are running a js function everytime the user makes some change in the text.

Javascript function:

```
function check(){
var correctAns = 2;
var input = document.getElementById('question1').value;
var btn = document.getElementById('submit');

if(input == correctAns){
btn.disabled = "false"; 
}else{
btn.disabled = "true";
}  
}
```

So, you will not be able to press the button, if you provide a wrong answer.
Hope this helps!